# want to remove punch time when Continuous IN accesscard time punched in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
2019-10-03 15:01:41.000 DOOR1   IN
2019-10-03 19:41:37.000 DOOR2   OUT
2019-10-04 09:38:13.000 DOOR1   IN
2019-10-04 14:34:52.000 DOOR1   OUT
2019-10-04 15:04:49.000 DOOR1   IN
2019-10-05 11:50:55.000 DOOR2   IN
2019-10-05 13:32:01.000 DOOR2   OUT
2019-10-05 14:05:57.000 DOOR1   IN
2019-10-05 20:41:03.000 DOOR1   OUT
```

I want to remove one/more IN or OUT punch when its come continuously, want to keep only last punch. That mean two IN punched, first punch want to remove as follow:

```
2019-10-04 15:04:49.000 DOOR1 IN - Want to remove this one
2019-10-05 11:50:55.000 DOOR2 IN
```

Comment: Hint to @TimBiegeleisen:  Not really.

Comment: You should *really-really* upgrade to a fresh, supported SQL Server version. This problem was solved in SQL Server 2012 and 2014 with the introduction or window functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(col3) over (order by col1) as prev_col3
      from t
     ) t
where not (prev_col3 = 'IN' and col3 = 'IN') or
      prev_col3 is null
```

If you actually want to *delete* the records (which I might not recommend), you can incorporate this logic into a `delete`:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*,
             lag(col3) over (order by col1) as prev_col3
      from t
     )
delete from todelete
    where prev_col3 = 'IN' and col3 = 'IN';
```

EDIT:

In ancient, unsupported versions of SQL Server, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (select top (1) t2.col3
              from t t2
              where t2.col1 < t.col1 
              order by t2.col1 desc
             ) as prev_col3
      from t
     ) t
where not (prev_col3 = 'IN' and col3 = 'IN') or
      prev_col3 is null
```

Comment: Who says there can't be an arbitrary number (e.g. 3 or more) of continuous ins or outs?

Comment: Thanks for answer, but for these i couldn't ask sql server upgrade in my office. I will be better it could be solved in sql server 2008.

Comment: SubrmaniA . . . Your office should only be using *supported* software.  They are at risk using software beyond the end of its life, because Microsoft no longer provides fixes, which can be critical for security.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . Now that the logic is *removing* the unwanted rows rather than keeping them, it should work for arbitrary sequences.

Comment: Its not removing first IN, its removing second IN. Anyhow i got solution. Thanks.